# How can I make this method work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

I want to hook Applist to a native processes, so I do not want to modify the headers, but I am not sure how?

`#import "XXX.h"`

`@class XXX, XXX, XXX` (I want Applist to hook in here)

Could something like this work?

`- (id)initWithInterface:(ALApplicationTableDataSource *dataSource)`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but couldn't you just make a category of the 'native process' you want to modify? In the category you'd just overwrite the method you like

Comment: Can you use an example please? When I say native I mean an iOS application like the settings app.

Comment: I think you need to specify your problem further. Are we talking on code level here? If so, please provide a name of a class or something.

Comment: Well put simply, I want to imbed the Applist class within the settings application. I found a few methods to call, but I think this will be the least complicated... I am interesting in trying out "PSListController" for the first test, from there I will add extra functions.